# how to create button increment by ng loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i try to create button increment,decrement

i need increment or decrement only one input, but it increment or decrement all of them

> in body.component.html

```
<div class="items-detail-detail" *ngFor="let detail of card.detail">
<div class="items-detail-information3">
  <div class="btn-block" >
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onDecrement()">
      <i class="material-icons">remove</i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group" >
    <input type="number" value="{{counter}}" class="form-control" style="text-align:center;" >
  </div>
  <div class="btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onIncrement()">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

> in body.component.ts

```
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
  private counter : number = 0; 
    onIncrement() {
      this.counter++
  } 
    onDecrement() {
      this.counter--
  } 
ngOnInit() {
}}
```

code will run like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgDtj.png)

and if i push [+] in top button , it will [+] all of input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRTQQ.png)

sorry for my english

thank you so much

Comment: everything looks fine except value="{{counter}}" use property binding  [value]="counter"

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain the counter variable for all `cards`.

### in body.component.html

```
<div class="items-detail-detail" *ngFor="let detail of card.detail">
<div class="items-detail-information3">
  <div class="btn-block" >
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onDecrement(detail)">
      <i class="material-icons">remove</i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group" >
    <input type="number" value="{{counter}}" class="form-control" style="text-align:center;" >
  </div>
  <div class="btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onIncrement(detail)">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

### in body.component.ts

```
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
    private counter: number = 0;
    onIncrement(item) {
        item.counter = item.counter ? item.counter + 1 : 1;
    }
    onDecrement(item) {
        item.counter = item.counter ? item.counter - 1 : 0;
    }
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: should create counter in card only?

i get card form json but don't need create counter in json.

Comment: It will automatically create counter, If not exists with every card.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because you have same `counter` for all of your card details.

```
<div class="input-group" >
    <input type="number" value="{{counter}}" class="form-control" style="text-align:center;" >
  </div>
```

If you want to update the value for a single card, you need to have different sets of `counter` values.

Comment: how to repeat declare variable counter for all ?

Answer (score 0):

@A.Yo, your detail must be a property "counter", so, you increment this property, not a global property

```
<div class="items-detail-detail" *ngFor="let detail of card.detail">
   ...
    <!--in button, you pass as argument "detail"-->
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onDecrement(detail)">
    ...
    <!--the value is NOT counter, it's detail.counter -->
    <input type="number" value="{{detail.counter}}" class="form-control" style="text-align:center;" >
    ...
    <!--idem with onIncrement--->
     <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onIncrement(detail)">
...
</div>

   //private counter : number = 0;  <--NOT, I don't use a "global" variable
    onIncrement(detail:any) {
      detail.counter++  //<--increment "detail.counter"
  } 
    onDecrement(detail:any) {
      detail.counter-- //<--decrement "detail.counter"
  }
```

You can simplify even the code using

```
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="detail.counter++">
<input type="number" value="{{detail.counter}}">
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="detail.counter--">
```

Comment: it can't declare variable for counter in file (all of component) ?

i need declare for counter in only page 
don't need get in json